Why do we not consider the normal force on chain falling onto a table?
I was solving a question which is as follows:
A chain AB of length l is located in a smooth horizontal tube so that its fraction of length h hangs freely and touches the surface of the table with its end B (Fig. 1.47). At a-certain moment the end A of the chain is set free. With what velocity will this end of the chain slip out of the tube?

My attempt to solve this was :
Let the portion already fallen on the ground at a time t be x. Therefore, the portion of the chain remaining in the tube is L-h-x.
Considering the fbd of the vertical portion of the chain, it experiences a vertical tension force, the force of gravity and an upthrust from the table which instantaneously brings a dm element at the bottom to rest. Taking $\lambda$ as the mass per unit length, we have
$$ {\lambda}hg - T - v\frac{dm}{dt} = {\lambda}ha $$
Since T also provides acceleration for the part of the chain in the tube,
$$ T = {\lambda}(L-h-x)a ;   v\frac{dm}{dt} = {\lambda}v^2 $$
$$ {\lambda}hg - {\lambda}(L-h-x)a - {\lambda}v^2 = {\lambda}ha $$
$$ hg - v^2 = {\frac{vdv}{dx}}(L-x) $$
This is a linear differential equation in $v^2$ and x which on solving gives,
$$ v = \sqrt{gh((1 - \frac{x}{L})^2 -1)} $$
putting x = L-h
$$ v = \sqrt{gh((\frac{h}{L})^2 -1)} $$
However the solution to this question that i found online does not consider the normal force due the table and simply writes the equation of motion of the vertical part of the chain as,
$$ {\lambda}hg - T = {\lambda}ha $$
$$ gh = \frac{vdv}{dx}(L-x) $$
which solves to give $ v = \sqrt {2ghln(\frac{L}{h})}$, which agrees with the answer given in the textbook.
Could anyone help me out with understanding why my equation is wrong and why we don't need to consider the force exerted by the table on the chain?

what's 'fbd'? What Is $a$?

I meant free body diagram, essentially a diagram of all the forces acting on the body

The normal force from the table cannot act on the entire rope length $h$. Only the infinitesimal part of the rope that actually hits the table or ends up eventually resting on it will experience a normal force. The section that is mid air does not experience any normal force.
So if you remove the normal force terms from your equations they will agree with the other answers your have researched.

To clarify, another way to say the same thing is to say that chains, ropes, strings etc. can support tension but NOT compression.
